# WCF with named pipes: how to allow parallel calls?

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

this is my first approach to WCF and named pipes.

What I have to do is a windows service listening on a named pipe while a small GUI tells it what to do through the pipe.

Everything works well: calls are made to the service, responses are delivered to the GUI and the job gets done. 
But if I send two concurrent requests from the GUI then the service will process them one by one: I would like to manually manage concurrency service-side and let it run both requests at the same time.

I've tried creating 2 different pipes for the 2 requests and it does what I need, but of course it's not a solution.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.0 and I can't change it.

Here's my example code:

SERVICE: pipe configuration

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CommandReceiver), new Uri[] {new Uri("net.pipe://localhost") });            
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICommandReceiver), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "myPipe");
host.Open();
```

SERVICE: Contract interface and implementation

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICommandReceiver
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Foo();

    [OperationContract]
    string Bar();
}

public class CommandReceiver : ICommandReceiver
{
    public string Foo()
    {
        //Do stuffs
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return "FOO";
    }

    public string Bar()
    {
        //Do stuffs
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        return "BAR";
    }
}
```

CLIENT: pipe configuration

```
ChannelFactory<ICommandReceiver> pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<ICommandReceiver>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/myPipe"));
ICommandReceiver serviceProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
```

CLIENT: call to the service

```
public string GetFoo() 
{
    return serviceProxy.Foo();
}
public string GetBar() 
{
    return serviceProxy.Bar();
}
```

Any advice on how to improve the whole thing, even switching to another communication method, would be really appreciate.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've solved this: first of all I was missing the following attribute on my contract implementation class:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class CommandReceiver : ICommandReceiver
{
  public string Foo()
  {
    //Do stuffs
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    return "FOO";
  }

  public string Bar()
  {
    //Do stuffs
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    return "BAR";
  }
}
```

And then I've discovered that the service works perfectly, but **not while debugging in visual studio**. Releasing and installing it on the system solved the issue.